# "apply something to someone" or "use something with someone"?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

Tell me please which phrasing sounds natural in the following context.

> The method of training **I used with my client**/**I applied to my client** was pretty challenging.

Would it be more grammatical and native to say *...I used to train... or ...I applied to train...*? If the second options are more correct and native, however longer, then which verb sounds more natural?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use or apply methods *with* a client, and apply methods *to* your training.

We can **apply** methods *to* an intangible thing such as a training regimen or an approach to doing something; we adapt the methods to the regimen or modify the approach in some way to  accommodate the methods.

> I applied these methods to my strength-building exercise regimen.

You could also say

> I applied these methods with John, my client.

And there, "with John" would be understood to mean "in the training regimen I have set up for John".

Comment: What about "use with" ? For example: "I used this method with Kate."

Comment: Yes, as I say in my opening sentence, "You would use or apply methods *with* a client".